# Override Base class methods in different class other than derived class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am newbie to Java concepts. I'm wondering what is the way to implement the following logic.

Consider the following **base class:**

```
public class A {

    public methodA() {
    ....
    }

    public methodB() {
    ..
    }
}
```

The **derived class:**

```
public class B extends A {

  // some B's stuff

    // Overriding base class method
    public methodA() {
    // Some common stuff
    super.methodA()
    }

    // Overriding base class method
    public methodB() {
    // some common stuff
    super.methodB()
    }

}
```

We don't have the access to modify base class methods. So we overriding the class and making changes.

Since overriding base class methods are in huge numbers, I want to move it to a separate class so that my derived class B is clean.

**Questions:**

1. Is there is any way to override the base class methods in a seperate class and link it to derived class.
2. There is same set of conditions is executed in overriding the super class methods. Is there is anyway to have common conditions to be executed before calling super class methods.

**Note:**

I can create a class C extends base class A and override the methods and then make class B to extend Class C.

But, I wondering if that is the proper way or is there is any other way to implement the above logic.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Since overriding base class methods are in huge numbers, I want to move it to a separate class so that my derived class B is clean." - even ignoring the semantic weirdness of doing that, it doesn't seem to *reduce* the mess in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is there is any way to override the base class methods in a seperate class and link it to derived class?

A: By definition, "overriding a method" must be done in some child class.

Q: Since overriding base class methods are in huge numbers, I want to move it to a separate class so that my derived class B is clean.

A: I'm not even sure what this means ... but it kind of sounds like you simply want a child class ... one that's less complex.  Perhaps "public class C extends B"?

Or maybe you even want to define an "interface", and have A (or some subclass) implement that interface?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is any way to override the base class methods in a separate class and link it to derived class.

No, the overrides must happen in `B`. However, since you have full control of `B`'s implementation, you can make another class, `HelperB`, put overrides there, and use it as `B`'s base class:

```
class A {
    // A's methods
}
class HelperB extends A {
    // Overrides of A's methods
}
class B extends HelperB {
    // B's methods
}
```

This would keep `B`'s logic free of overrides of `A`'s methods.

> Is there is anyway to have common conditions to be executed before calling super class methods?

Move common logic into separate methods inside `A`. Make these methods `protected`, and use it from inside `A`'s implementations. Now you can reuse the same computations in `B`, as well as in all other classes derived from `A`:

```
class A {
    // Evaluates a common condition
    protected boolean condition1() { ... }
    // Uses a common condition in the base class
    public void method1() {
        if (condition1()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
class B extends HelperB {
    public void method1() {
        // Some B-specific code
        // Uses a common condition in the base class
        if (condition1()) {
            ...
        }
        // More B-specific code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create another class C and extend it to ContextWrapper and place all your methods in it. To use the methods in Class C, initialize an object of class C in either Class A or B and call it's methods through the object of C. Make sure the methods are public in Class C.